# Is there a way to make Bazel work with transitive repositories?

Tags: build, repository, bazel, workspace

I work with a massive codebase distributed across many repositories and using even more third-party dependencies. The goal is to make the build hermetic and I contemplate using Bazel to achieve it. On the one hand, Bazel has git_repository rule to refer to the external repos in the WORKSPACE file. On the other hand, WORKSPACE files are not loaded recursively, so to get to indirect dependencies I need to build all inclusive WORKSPACE file somehow. I wonder if somebody already tackled that problem using Bazel or some other existing tools. Is there a way to expand the WORKSPACE as part of the build? May be WORKSPACE can #include other (generated) files?

Answer (score 2):

WORKSPACE files can [load](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/build-ref.html#load) and then call [macros](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/macros.html), which gives similar functionality to #include.

A common pattern is each project having a macro which calls macros (for dependencies on other projects) and creates `*_archive` rules (for dependencies directly on files to download) so it builds. For example, protobuf has [protobuf_deps](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/protobuf_deps.bzl) to implement this pattern. If you create a repository with protobuf (using `git_repository`, or `http_archive`, or any of the other repository rules), then you can load that macro and call it, and you'll automatically get all the transitive dependencies.

For example ([from Chromium](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/google/protobuf/+/HEAD/examples/WORKSPACE)):

```py
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")
# This com_google_protobuf repository is required for proto_library rule.
# It provides the protocol compiler binary (i.e., protoc).
http_archive(
    name = "com_google_protobuf",
    strip_prefix = "protobuf-master",
    urls = ["https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/archive/master.zip"],
)
load("@com_google_protobuf//:protobuf_deps.bzl", "protobuf_deps")
protobuf_deps()
```

I'm showing `http_archive` because it's easier to work with, but you can easily change it to `git_archive` if you want.

Another common pattern which makes this all work is the way `protobuf_deps` checks `native.existing_rule` before creating each `http_archive`. That allows you to instantiate a specific version (or from a specific source, etc) of the dependency directly in your WORKSPACE file to override the one protobuf would otherwise bring in.

Comment: Brian, I am trying to follow the pattern you explained, but as far as I understand it only works one level deep and does not work further down the chain of the transitive dependencies. In the WORKSPACE file we can declare repo, load .bzl file and invoke a function from it. Inside that function we can declare more repos, BUT we cannot use "load" from within the function and therefore cannot use this pattern recursively. We still have to manually roll up all "load" statements and _deps function invocations for all transitive dependencies to the root WORKSPACE file. Not maintainable. Your ideas?

Comment: You can bundle up each part (`http_archive` and `load`) for your transitive dependencies in separate .bzl files. These can then be used recursively. [Bazel Federation](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-federation) uses this pattern for many repositories, for example. Their list of steps for [adding your repo to the Federation](https://bazelbuild.github.io/bazel-federation/how_to_integrate.html#add-your-repo-to-the-federation) talks about each piece.